Upgraded to Angular v15 and mat badges won't show text on mat-icons. But will show special characters, like '&, !, ...'. Was working before on v14
<button mat-flat-buton>
  <mat-icon matBadge="1">home</mat-icon>
</button>


<button mat-flat-buton>
  <mat-icon matBadge="!">home</mat-icon>
</button>


I've checked the html and I see the span with the text there

stackblitz link
any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

The property matBadge only accepts icons of material-icons, the reason you are not able to view the text is because of the property font-family: 'Material Icons'; from the class .material-icons, we can override this with the below SCSS
Componnent level using ::ng-deep
::ng-deep .show-text-on-badge > mat-icon > span {
  font-family: initial !important;
}

Global style level
.show-text-on-badge > mat-icon > span {
  font-family: initial !important;
}

We can add the class (.show-text-on-badge) to configure it to accept text.
<button mat-flat-buton class="show-text-on-badge">
  <mat-icon matBadge="1">home</mat-icon>
</button>

You can style the text to your liking using the above method.
Stackblitz Demo

Thanks Naren! That did the trick, had no idea the font family was the culprit.
